# Labelling lines in ggplot2 with their gradients and changing legend characteristics

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking at the change in maximum temperature per month, from 1954-2000 using data thus:

http://pastebin.com/37zUkaA4

I have decided to only plot the abline for each month on the graph for clarity.  My code is as follows:

```
OxTemp$Month <- factor(OxTemp$Month, levels=c("January", "February", "March","April", "May", "June", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"), ordered=TRUE)

p<-ggplot(OxTemp, aes(x=Year, y=MaxT, group=Month, colour=Season, linetype=Month))

p+geom_smooth(method = 'lm',size = 1, se = F)
```

Which gives me the following plot:

[image]

I was wondering if there was a way to:

a) Change the colours in the "Month" legend to match the colours in the "Season" legend

b) Make the legends a little wider so that the linetypes are more visible

c) Add a label of each line's gradient to the plot, such that to the right handside of each line the slope value is displayed

Many thanks!

Comment: It's alright. You know now for the next time. Trying it out. Let's cleanup the comments

Comment: I have edit the link into the question.

Comment: you can add `theme(legend.key.width = unit(4, "cm"))` to get the lines in legend bigger. I don't think it's that easily possible to get the colours for "Month" as you already have used the colour aesthetic on "Season".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
OxTemp <- read.table("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=37zUkaA4",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(ggplot2)
OxTemp$Month <- factor(OxTemp$Month, 
                       levels=c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar","Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), ordered=TRUE)
OxTemp$Season <- factor(OxTemp$Season, 
                       levels=c("Spring", "Summer", "Autumn", "Winter"), ordered=TRUE)

library(plyr)
slopedat <- ddply(OxTemp,.(Month),function(df) data.frame(slope=format(signif(coef(lm(MaxT~Year,data=df))[2],2),scientific=-2),
                                                          y=max(predict(lm(MaxT~Year,data=df)))))



p <- ggplot(OxTemp, aes(x=Year, y=MaxT)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(group=Month, colour=Season, linetype=Month),method = 'lm',size = 1, se = F) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("Winter"= 4, "Spring" = 1, "Summer" = 2,"Autumn" = 3)) +
  geom_text(data=slopedat,aes(x=2005,y=y,label=paste0("slope = ",slope))) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1950, 2010)) +
  guides(linetype=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=c("Jan"= 4, "Feb" = 4, "Mar" = 1,
                                                          "Apr" = 1, "May" = 1, "Jun" = 2,
                                                          "Jul" = 2, "Aug" = 2, "Sep" = 3, 
                                                          "Oct" = 3, "Nov" = 3, "Dec" = 4)),keywidth=5))

print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Can I ask a quick extra question?  I have plotted the same graph for the Min Temp data (also in the pastebin link), and then for the average of the two, but some of the slope labels overlap.  Is there a tool to move them about?  Thank you :-)

Comment: Well, you need to find a better estimator for `slopedat$y`. You could also define the coordinates manually. It might also be possible to use `position_dodge`.

Comment: Thanks Roland.  Position dodge doesn't seem to make any difference.  Can i ask how I would specify the coordinates one by one for each slope?

Comment: Just change `slopedat$y` to whichever values suit your needs.