# Legends and labelling smooth fitted lines + additional lines using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on visualising some patterns in network data and have some issues labelling lines, where I have multiple classes of lines:

1. loess lines for each factor (network)
2. a baseline at y=4000
3. a gam line that acts on all of the data (not factored)

Now, stack overflow has helped get me to this point (thanks!), but I feel like I have run into a brick wall for what I need to do:

A. provide a legend entry for the line #3

B. label each line on the graph (as per #1 #2 #3 - so 8 lines total)

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
p <- ggplot(network_data, aes(x=timeofday,y=dspeed, colour=factor(network)))+stat_smooth(method="loess",formula=y~x,se=FALSE)
p <- p + stat_function(fun=function(x)4000, geom="line", linetype="dashed", aes(colour="Baseline"))
p <- p + xlab("Time of Day (hr)") + ylab("Download Speed (ms)")
p <- p + theme(axis.line=element_line(colour="black"))

# add the gam line, colouring it purple for now
q <- layer(data=network_data, mapping=aes(x=timeofday,y=dspeed), stat="smooth"
       , stat_params=list(method="gam", formula=y~s(x), se=FALSE), geom="smooth", geom_params=list(colour="purple"), position=position_identity()) 

graph <- p+q # add the layer

#legend
graph <- graph+scale_colour_discrete(name="network")

# set up the origin correctly and axes etc
graph2 <- graph + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,6500), expand=c(0,0), breaks=c(0,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000)) + scale_x_datetime(limits=as.POSIXct(c("2015-04-13 00:00:01","2015-04-13 23:59:59")), expand = c(0, 0), breaks=date_breaks("1 hour"), labels=date_format("%H"))
```

Happy to consider other packages, but ggplot2 seems to be the best so far.

Is there anyway to do this 'automatically' (through programming) as I am trying to automate the generation of these graphs?

I have made the data available here as a .Rda file:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5268020/network_data.Rda

And here is an image of the current plot:

[image]

Comment: not sure I understand: for A) there is already a legend, and B) the legend also labels the lines, you want text above each line labeling #1,...,#8?

Comment: The gam line does not appear in the legend. It seems that I needed to add this as a layer (q). I also want to have each line labelled -- using direct.label I could not figure out how to add a label for each line at the end of the fitted line (and baseline).

Comment: I've been thinking of other approaches. Though perhaps clumsy, I am looking into creating a copy of the data, replacing the Network data in the copy with 'one factor' (naming it "Overall" or something similar) and then combining the two sets of data. I am trying this tonight.

Comment: Alright, I think I've solved one problem which is to get everything in the legend. Once I sort this out with labels, I will answer the question properly, but I added the following code at the beginning:`network_data_2 <- network_data # create duplicate
network_data_2$Network <- c("Overall") #replace all levels
network_data_combined <- rbind(network_data, network_data_2)`

Comment: for the labels, you can create another data frame with one row per line with an x-coordinate (max time) and a y (final download speed) for each line, and use geom_text like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123936/labelling-lines-in-ggplot2-with-their-gradients-and-changing-legend-characterist?rq=1) there are some other questions like this floating around

Comment: Thanks rawr--I'd seen that one a few days ago and bookmarked it. What a great resource this community is. I should also note that while I was getting warnings in my previous approach for using LOESS for more than 1000 points, I find that using LOESS with a customised span for my data yields best 'smooth curve' visualisation. I'll post up the finalised code when I get this all done.

Answer (score 0):

For q B, try `annotate` and manually code in the location and text for the label of each line. Seems unnecessary given the legend.
http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/annotate.html

Comment: Thanks--yes I can understand it being seen as unnecessary, but my client would like us to be able to see what we can do. I'll try this out soon.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the client is always right :)   With annotate, it means that it can't be done automatically for different datasets--I tried direct.label with last.points but I think it just places it on the last point of data for each factor (still skipping the baseline and the gam, iirc) rather than on the fitted line.