# How to plot lines of geom_smooth with the p values of the lm model result?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot my date in ggplot like this: [image], with line type been determined by the p values of the smooth lines (i.e., dash line if the regression is not significant, and solid line when it is). Before I post this question, I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123936/labelling-lines-in-ggplot2-with-their-gradients-and-changing-legend-characterist) in this forum, but they normally deal with labels, not the line itself. 
Belwo is my failure code with sample data. Thanks in advance for your kind help.

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(id = 1: 100, 
                   x = rnorm(100,2,0.5), 
                   y = rnorm(100, 20, 5),
                  varA = rep(letters[1:4], 25), 
                  varB = factor(sample(c(50,100,150), 100, TRUE)))

pvdat <- ddply(dat,.(varA,varB), function(df) data.frame(pvalue=format(signif(summary(lm(y~x,data=df))[[4]][2, 4], 2),scientific=-2),
                                                          lty = ifelse(summary(lm(y~x,data=df))[[4]][2, 4] > 0.05, 0, 1)))
ggplot(data= dat, aes(x = x, y = y, col = as.factor(varB))) + geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(linetype = pvdat$lty)) + facet_grid(. ~ as.factor(varA), scale = "free_x")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- `pvdata$lty` is continuous, but `linetype` requires a factor
- pvdata has ten items but dat has 100, so ggplot does not know how to make a mapping between the two

To change your numeric column to a factor, you need `as.factor()`, and to make the mapping you can use the `merge()` function to make a single data frame with the values from pvdat mapped for each element of dat. Putting these together:

```
ggplot(data= merge(dat,pvdat,by = c("varA","varB")), aes(x = x, y = y, col = as.factor(varB))) + geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(linetype = as.factor(lty))) + facet_grid(. ~ as.factor(varA), scale = "free_x")
```

will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks very much @SDS0 for the help. That's exactly what I am looking for. Your code also helps me out on the entire ggplot mapping logic which trapped me for quite a long time. Thanks~